# Decoding Base64 throws error in javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to decode the bye array of a PNG file in base64 and then convert it into Binary using the javascript,in android mobile app.

> `var binary = escape(atob(byteDataFromServer.split(',')[1]));`

**Error**

> "atob' failed the string to be decoded contains characters outside of
>   the latin1 range"

Comment: Are you using the native implementation of `atob` or a polyfill? Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9786592/741043

Comment: native implementation,  am already getting the byte as base64 @KerriShotts